# Definition of meromorphic $q$-differential

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

In Farkas Kra riemann surfaces textbook, it defines a meromorphic $q$-differential as follows:

> Let $q$ be an integer. By a (meromorphic) $q$-differential $\omega$ on $M$ we mean an assignment of a meromorphic function $f$ to each local coordinate $z$ on $M$ so that
> $$f(z)dz^q$$
> is invariantly defined.

It's not clear (to me) how this should be interpreted. What is $dz^q$ here?

Comment: They certainly mean $dz^q=\underbrace{dz \otimes \ldots \otimes dz}_q$  as an element of $\Omega_U^q = \underbrace{\Omega_U^1 \otimes_{\Bbb{C}(U)} \ldots \otimes_{\Bbb{C}(U)} \Omega_U^1}_q$ where $U\subset M$ is an open, $\Omega^1_U$ is the space of meromorphic 1-forms and $\Bbb{C}(U)$ is the space of meromorphic functions on $U$ and $z$ a chart $U\to \Bbb{C}$. When $U$ is small enough for such a chart to exist then $\Omega_U^q = \Bbb{C}(U) dz^q$ which tells you the zeros/poles. So $U\mapsto\Omega_U^q$ forms a sheaf and you can look at $\Omega_M^q$ and what are the zeros/poles of its elements.

Comment: @reuns Farkas & Kra don't say anything about tensor product. Is it ok to understand it as a formal symbol?

Comment: Sure the tensor product is some kind of formal symbol. All you need is $g(z)(dw(z))^q = g(z) w'(z)^q (dz)^q$ to make changes of charts. Try with $M=SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\backslash \Bbb{H}$ the modular curve and $j'(z)^2 (dz)^2$ (the $j$-invariant) so $j'(z)^2 $ is a weight $4$ meromorphic modular form, that is $j'(\gamma(z))^2= \gamma'(z)^{-2} j'(z)$ for $\gamma\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$.

Comment: @reuns Ah, I see. Actually the reason I ask this question (what is $dz^q$) is because there's a statement in the same book, which states that 'Since abelian differentials exist (i.e. holomorphic differential), the $q$-canonical class is just the $q$th power of the canonical class'.  It's written in the section introducing divisor. Could you explain why or should I post it as a separate question?

Comment: If $\omega,\omega_2$ are (non-zero) meromorphic $q$-differentials then $\omega=f \omega_2$ for some meromorphic function. No need to assume an holomorphic differential, for any meromorphic function $(dg)^q$ works too. So the $\Bbb{C}(M)$ module of $q$-differentials is free of rank $1$. You need to look at $(dz)^q$ for a chart only to define the zeros/poles of a $q$-differential.